# Pagination Not working in VF Page

Tags: visualforce, pagination, standardsetcontroller

```
   public void last() 
    {
          Integer pageNum = reviewSetController.getPageNumber();
        try
        {          
            system.debug('page numberin try-'+pageNum);
            reviewSetController.setPageNumber(pageNum);
            reviewSetController.last();    
            sobjectList=(List<Sobject>)reviewSetController.getRecords(); 
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {     
              system.debug('pagenumber in exception---'+reviewSetController.getPageNumber()); 
              string excepn=string.valueof(ex);
              Boolean result=excepn.contains('Modified rows exist in the records collection!');
              if(result == true)
              {
                  string errMsg=string.valueof(ex)+'\n'+ 'Please cancel the changes before leaving the Page.';
                  ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, errMsg));
              }      
              else 
              {     
                    ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
              }
        }   

    }
```

1. I have an issue in the setting of page number.I have added two debug
   statements over here.
2. The one inside the try block is giving the actual page number. i.e, if i'm currently in page 3 it is giving page 3.
3. The one inside the Catch block is always giving the page number as 1 whenever an exception occurs.
4. The issue occurs for only last , first method not for previous/next.

Could someone suggest why this is happening? Bcoz the vf page actually remains on page number 3 but the page number is getting updated to 1 whenever an exception occurs.

Comment: Try returning a `PageReference` instead of `void` in the method.  Even just `return null;` might help

Comment: Thanks Brian.I tried but it doesn't work.